# If statement between JTable cell and Variable

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtable

I'm working on a pos (like openbravo or dolibarr) panel in Java. When a user presses a `JButton` after getting the product info, the product is added to a `JTable`. However, if he presses the button twice or more, the same product is added again, so I could have a `JTable` with 2,3 or 4 same lines. That's why I'm trying to limit that.

My idea, is to compare the cells containing product id in the `JTable` and the variable containing product id in the product info form.

The problem is, when I open the panel for the first time, my `JTable` is empty, so my `if` statement can't work.

I need some advice.

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(idprod!=0)
    {   
        montanttva1 = prixtotalttc - prixtotalht;
        int row = tableaupan.getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            int test =(int) (tableaupan.getModel().getValueAt(i,0)); 
            if (test==idprod)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product is already in the basket !","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);     
            }
            else
            {
            modele.addCaisse(new Caisse(idprod,JTitre.getText().toString(),cqte,prixunittcc,prixht,montanttva1,prixtotalht,prixtotalttc,typetva,tva));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nothing to add in the basket !", "Errorr",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                  
    }
}
});
```

Thanks, with your comments I understand my logic error. Now I must add a method like this in my model ?

```
public boolean containsId(int idprod) {
*condition for true*
return true;
*condition for false*
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this solution, and It works :

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
if(idprod!=0)
{
    montanttva1 = prixtotalttc - prixtotalht;
    int row = tableaupan.getRowCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        if(tableaupan.getValueAt(i,0).equals(idprod))
        {
             OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product is already in the basket !","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);     
             return;                       
        }
    }
modele.addCaisse(new Caisse(idprod,JTitre.getText().toString(),cqte,prixunittcc,prixht,montanttva1,prixtotalht,prixtotalttc,typetva,tva));
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nothing to add to basket !", "Errorr",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect. You compare your ID with every row. And for each row, if the row'sID doesn't match with the product ID, you add a new row.

The logic should be:

```
if (modele.containsId(idprod)) {
    addProduct();
}
else {
    showError();
}
```

Now you just need to add the `containsId()` method to your model.

Comment: I compare ID with every row because I'm trying to have a single row for each product. So, when a product is added in the basket, it must be impossible to add another row for this product. Maybe a more easy solution is to clear the product info form.

Comment: Re-read your code, and re-read my answer. What your code does is: "for each row, if the row's id is not equal to the product ID, then I add a new row). If you have 4 rows, all with a different product ID, you'll thus add 4 new rows.